Get 'Last Build ID' for a build from artifactory using jfrog cli
Does anyone know if there is a 'jf rt' cli command to get that Last Build ID for a build (other than using a slow search 'jf rt s --build' in the request) ?
I have a problem where artifactory searches for artifacts in my master builds are taking very long, both when I search using 'jf rt s' and when I download using artifactory jenkins plugin.
After investigation, our IT team identified that the artifactory SQL search is very inefficient, pulling a huge amount of data to the client and searching through it, instead of having an effficient indexed retrieval.  Seems to be due to some artifacts being in many releases.  Any jf rt search I do with '--build' is very slow, even if I give it the full path to an artifact.
My question here is trying to find a workaround for the case where I need to get from the lastest master build.
I see in jfrog UI, under 'Builds' there is a column labelled 'Last Build ID that has the latest build number for each release, which is exactly what I need.
